# aura:component fileUpload

Tags: salesforce1-app, fileupload, lightning-components

create a lightning component to upload images (fileUpload).
that component goes to the registration page of a custom object, but when entering the salesforce1 application I cannot see the component.
If I enter it as a tab it shows it to me, but I need it to be on the registration page because it needs to capture the custom object ID.

Any recommendation?

Thank you.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The older version of mobile app does not show any lightning component that are placed in home page and record page but shows for application pages whereas the newer version of mobile app which has been introduced as part of spring 20 release, All the components that are placed on lightning page will be available in mobile as well.

You can check this trailhead module on 
[Build a Custom Record Page for Lightning Experience and the Salesforce Mobile App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_recordpage)